# Fragment crashes on rotation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this fragment, but anytime I try to change rotation it just crashes with error messages. I have an Activity with navigation drawer that has framelayout inside for showing the fragments, all other fragments work except this one ...

Here is the code for fragment :

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment implements OnNavigationListener,
        View.OnClickListener, View.OnKeyListener {

    private int mEventId;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private String mLatitude, mLongitude, mTitle, mContentMessage, mDateTime,
            mCurentLatitude, mCurentLongitude, mShowtimeId;
    private boolean noNavigationForYou;

    private RatingBar mRatingBarNotSet, mRatingBarSet;
    private ScrollView mScrollView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressLoader;
    private TextView mTitleView, mContentMessageView, mDateTimeView,
            mUserRatingSetText;
    private LinearLayout mRatingSet, mRatingNotSet;
    private View rootView, content, loader;
    private Button mEditRatingButton, mViewComentsButton,
            mAllRatingsNotSetButton, mAllRatingsSetButton, mShowOnMapButton,
            mShowNavigationButton;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);
        content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_content, container,
                false);
        loader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_loader, container,
                false);
        noNavigationForYou = false;
        setUpParentStuff();
        setUpTitle();
        mViewComentsButton = (Button) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_coments_button);
        mAllRatingsNotSetButton = (Button) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_ratings_button);
        mAllRatingsSetButton = (Button) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_ratings_set_button);
        mEditRatingButton = (Button) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_edit_user_rating_button);
        mShowOnMapButton = (Button) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_navigation_showonmap);
        mShowNavigationButton = (Button) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_navigation_shownavigation);

        if (noNavigationForYou) {
            mShowNavigationButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Button test = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.tst_button);
        test.setOnClickListener(this);

        mViewComentsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAllRatingsSetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAllRatingsNotSetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mEditRatingButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mShowOnMapButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mShowNavigationButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mProgressLoader = (ProgressBar) loader
                .findViewById(R.id.event_loader_bar);
        mProgressLoader.setIndeterminate(true);

        mRatingBarNotSet = (RatingBar) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_rating_bar_not_set);
        mRatingBarSet = (RatingBar) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_rating_bar);

        mRatingBarNotSet.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingChangeListener(
                mEventId, getActivity(), getFragmentManager()));

        mTitleView = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.event_details_title);
        mContentMessageView = (TextView) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_subtitle);
        mDateTimeView = (TextView) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_date);
        mUserRatingSetText = (TextView) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_user_rating_textview);

        mScrollView = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
        mScrollView.addView(loader);

        mRatingSet = (LinearLayout) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_rating_set_view);
        mRatingNotSet = (LinearLayout) content
                .findViewById(R.id.event_details_rating_not_set_view);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true); // aby bolo share option
        rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        rootView.requestFocus();

        rootView.setOnKeyListener(this);

        new FetchEventDetails().execute(URL);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setUpTitle() {
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(bundle.getString("title"));

    }

    private void setUpParentStuff() {
        bundle = getArguments();
        mEventId = bundle.getInt("id");
        mCurentLatitude = bundle.getString("userCurLat");
        mCurentLongitude = bundle.getString("userCurLng");
        mShowtimeId = bundle.getString("showTimeId");
        if (mCurentLatitude == null) {
            noNavigationForYou = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_share_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item
                .getActionProvider();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mTitle + " - " + mDateTime);
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(bundle.getString("title"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.event_details_coments_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ComentsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", mEventId);
            getActivity().startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.event_details_ratings_button:
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), RatingsActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("id", mEventId);
            getActivity().startActivity(in);
            break;
        case R.id.event_details_ratings_set_button:
            Intent inn = new Intent(getActivity(), RatingsActivity.class);
            inn.putExtra("id", mEventId);
            getActivity().startActivity(inn);
            break;
        case R.id.event_details_edit_user_rating_button:
            DialogHelper dh = new DialogHelper(getActivity(),
                    getFragmentManager());
            AlertDialog dialog = dh.showNonEmptyRatingDialog(mRatingBarSet,
                    mEventId, mUserRatingSetText.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.event_navigation_showonmap:
            Intent newMap = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
            newMap.putExtra("lat", mLatitude);
            newMap.putExtra("lng", mLongitude);
            newMap.putExtra("etitle", mTitle);
            getActivity().startActivity(newMap);
            break;
        case R.id.event_navigation_shownavigation:
            Intent newNavigation = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
            newNavigation.putExtra("lat", mLatitude);
            newNavigation.putExtra("lng", mLongitude);
            newNavigation.putExtra("etitle", mTitle);
            newNavigation.putExtra("clat", mCurentLatitude);
            newNavigation.putExtra("clng", mCurentLongitude);
            getActivity().startActivity(newNavigation);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            getFragmentManager().popBackStack("events", // null
                    getFragmentManager().POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(bundle.getString("title_r"));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private class FetchEventDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventid", String
                    .valueOf(mEventId)));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("showid", mShowtimeId));

            JSONObject jobj = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, parameters, "GET");
            Log.i("jobj", jobj.toString());
            try {
                JSONArray pom = jobj.getJSONArray(KEY_RESULTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < pom.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject eventDetailsJ = pom.getJSONObject(i);
                    mTitle = eventDetailsJ.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    mDateTime = eventDetailsJ.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    mContentMessage = eventDetailsJ.getString(KEY_DETAILS);
                    mLatitude = eventDetailsJ.getString(KEY_LAT);
                    mLongitude = eventDetailsJ.getString(KEY_LNG);

                    mDateTime = mDateTime.substring(8, 10) + "."
                            + mDateTime.substring(5, 7) + "."
                            + mDateTime.substring(0, 4) + " "
                            + mDateTime.substring(11, 16) + ", ";
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mTitleView.setText(mTitle);
            mContentMessageView.setText(mContentMessage);
            mDateTimeView.setText(mDateTime);
            new FetchUserRating().execute(URL);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }


    private class FetchUserRating extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, List<String>> {
        private String result = null;
        private String result_text = null;
        private UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        private List<String> results;

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            results = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userFunctions
                    .getUserName(getActivity())));
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_event", String
                    .valueOf(mEventId)));

            JSONObject jobj = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, parameters, "GET");

            try {
                JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray(KEY_RESULTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject ratingJ = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (ratingJ.has(KEY_USER_RATING_VAL)) {
                        results.add(ratingJ.getString(KEY_USER_RATING_VAL));
                        results.add(ratingJ.getString(KEY_USER_RATING_TEXT));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> results) {
            if (results.size() > 0) {
                result = results.get(0);
                result_text = results.get(1);
                mRatingBarSet.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(null);
                mRatingBarSet.setRating(Float.parseFloat(result));
                mRatingBarSet.setIsIndicator(true);
                mUserRatingSetText.setText(result_text);
                mRatingNotSet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mRatingSet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mScrollView.removeAllViews();
            mScrollView.addView(content);
            super.onPostExecute(results);
        }
    }
}
```

And the errors :

```
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257): Process: com.kulturnepodujatia, PID: 17257
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.kulturnepodujatia/com.kulturnepodujatia.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3517)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3535)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3735)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1323)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1341)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:484)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at com.kulturnepodujatia.fragments.EventFragment.onDestroy(EventFragment.java:262)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:1913)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1881)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5402)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1117)
04-08 20:49:16.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3504)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use commitAllowingStateLoss() and it should be ok.

Comment: Are you sure you are using this method for the fragment transaction that use this fragment? It should work.

Comment: yes, this is from the "parent" fragment `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, frag).addToBackStack("events").commitAllowingStateLoss();`

Comment: Try to remove the code in the fragment onDestroy(). All the fragments implement the onDestroy() in this way?

Comment: I just noticed this, I put that in the wrong method ... meh sometimes I have to put code somewhere else to see my stupidity ... thx